# How to get info about the mentioned users (discord.py bot)?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Someone uses the command !getname @testuser, the bot gets the name as a string and could do with it whatever I want. I can't find anything about on the Internet. Maybe the answer is just too obvious.

Also, how could I get the avatar of the mentioned user? And download it or whatever.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at converters: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#converters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by specifying that the type of a parameter is `discord.Member` :

```
import requests

@bot.command()
async def getname(ctx, member: discord.Member):

    await ctx.send(f'User name: {member.name}, id: {member.id}')

    with requests.get(member.avatar_url_as(format='png')) as r:
        img_data = r.content
    with open(f'{member.name}.png', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(img_data)
```

Comment: Thanks! I used `member: discord.member` (with lowercase m) the whole time. That's why it didn't work :(

Comment: You seem like someone who knows what he does, so I have another question. How can I create a webhook? Not manually obviously. I want my bot to create the webhook and return me the URL. I know how I can post stuff, edit the webhook, etc., but I can't find a way to create one.

Comment: @hallowed I think that [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=webhook#webhook-support) is what you want.

Comment: It isn't, but I found what I wanted. Thanks anyway! `webhook = await ctx.channel.create_webhook()` That's what I tried to find;)